# How do I run a Linear Regression within PySpark and restrict the Intercept to be zero?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, linear-regression, intercept

I have existing code within SAS that runs a fairly simple Proc Regression.  I need to convert this to PySpark.

I am looking to run a linear regression within PySpark and specify that the intercept should be 0.  I have 2 input columns (INPUT1 and INPUT2), and an output column (OUTPUT) on my data_input and would additionally like to apply the restriction that INPUT1 weighting = 1 - INPUT2 weighting.

My code currently looks like this but I can't see where I can add the required settings:

```
vectorAssembler=VectorAssembler(inputCols=['INPUT1', 'INPUT2'], outputCol='features')
regression_df=vectorAssembler.transform(data_input)
regression_df=regression_df.select(['features', 'OUTPUT'])

lr=LinearRegression(featuresCol='features', labelCol='OUTPUT')
model=lr.fit(regression_df)
print("Coefficients: " + str(model.coefficients))
print("Intercept: +str(model.intercept))
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this `pyspark` doc: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression

As you can see, you can set many arguments to the `LinearRegression` object, one of them being `fitIntercept` which is set to `True` by default. You can also set other parameters for your `LinearRegression` model here, such as the solver, loss function and so on. 
Furthermore, there are additional methods you can call on the `LinearRegression`, one of them being `setFitIntercept`. You can find more info here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression.setFitIntercept

Hope this helps!